# Django - using filter/exclude doesn't work

Tags: django, django-views

i have this code:

```
import datetime

today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)

pickingYesterday = Order.objects.exclude(actionorder__type__name = 'In process',actionorder__dateCreation__lt=today_min).filter(actionorder__type__name = 'Completed', actionorder__dateCreation__lt=today_min).count()
```

I want to filter out all the orders which these conditions apply for 
yesterday.

```
class Order(models.Model):

class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 100)

class actionOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    Type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    dateCreation  = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get yesterday's date by doing:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
today = date.today()
today = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.date)
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to get orders with order action as "complete" as of today, but was not "complete" yesterday, right? If so, you could do:

```
pickingYesterday = Order.objects.filter(actionorder__type__name='Completed', 
                                        actionorder__dateCreation__gte=today) \
                                .exclude(actionorder__type__name='Completed', 
                                         actionorder__dateCreation__lte=today, 
                                         actionorder__dateCreation__gte=yesterday).count()
```

Comment: not only 'Completed', is possible that a order can have one or many action 'In process' from yesterday but today was completed. that Order must be returned but if the order was completed yesterday should not be returned.

Comment: i forget to say that the dateCreation is a datetime field, for that reason I calculate the date in that way.

Comment: You need to edit your post to show us your model for `Order` and `ActionOrder`. Sounds like your `ActionOrder` has a foreign key to `Order` and `ActionOrder` records the status of an order, is that right? If so your query wouldn't work at all.

Comment: look, this is a minimum version of the models:

class Order(models.Model):

class type(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField( max_length = 100)

class actionorder(models.Model):
 order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
 type = models.ForeignKey(Order)
 dateCreation  = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True )

Comment: What I meant is that you should edit your original question and add above model code. This way more people can see it and the format is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look i try this and works,opinions?

```
from django.db.models import Q
import datetime

today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)

pickingYesterday = Order.objects.filter(actionorder__type__name = 'Completed', actionorder__dateCreation__lt=today_min).filter(actionorder__type__name = 'In process',actionorder__dateCreation__gte=today_min).count()
pickingYesterday += Order.objects.filter(actionorder__type__name = 'Completed', actionorder__dateCreation__lt=today_min).filter(~Q(actionorder__type__name = 'In process')).count()
```